# Cannot connect to Azure App Service for Remote Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2022, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug an  application deployed in azure app service.
Using Azure Portal, enabled debugging and Client Authentication mode - Allow, that has the fall back option of SSO.
Back in VS2022,  I start Debug/Connect to Process. I see the correct list of Subscriptions, Resource groups and running processes. When I try to connect to the process that I need to debug, Visual Studio shows a dialog 'Unable to  connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named (all the details are correct here) Operation not supported. Unknown Error ox80aa0001

Does anyone have a clue why? Does this sound like a firewall issue?